# What is a possible causes that Picture-in-Picture is not enabled inside my web document?

Tags: javascript, html, picture-in-picture

I think that my question is pretty simple from a title, bellow are additional information.

I have a little project in Laravel, and I want to implement Real-Time Video Calls using ApiRTC.
When Local Stream is loaded (I can see myself in a  element), it should also have a PIP function.. But unfortunately, it is not the case.

Error is "requestPictureInPicture is not a function", from that I concluded that PIP API is not enabled.. but I can't understand why?

P.S. It is enabled in my browser, I checked that inside about:config.

Comment: `about:config` this means you are in Firefox, right?

Comment: Yes I am in Firefox, but it wont work in Chrome also.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox still doesn't support the [PictureInPicture webAPI](https://github.com/w3c/picture-in-picture).
They are starting the implementation of ["user initiated Picture-in-Picture"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1519885) and do allow `right-click -> Picture-in-Picture` on elements pointing to videos in the current Nightly, or behind flags in more stable versions, but that's not the same thing.

And for whatever reasons, they indeed still don't even allow this when the video points to a MediaStream. In current stable (with flags) you can workaround this by first enabling PiP from a "normal" video, and only then switch the video's source to the MediaStream, but this will just crash the browser in current Nightly, so it's hardly a good solution...

The best is to wait for it's stabilized, and meanwhile, use a browser that does support this API.

Comment: But, how I use PiP on many other websites through Firefox?
YouTube, here on StackOverflow and many other...
Also, I have a same problem with Google Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by you use PiP on these websites? The Picture-in-Picture web API isn't implemented at all in FF, so these websites are not using it. Do you mean you click the PiP icon that appears? This is not part of the web API, this is still experimental, and this still doesn't support MediaStreams. However [that](https://jsfiddle.net/pd7rw1k9/) should work on Chrome just fine.

Comment: Yes, I mean that I can click on the Pip icon and move video anywhere on the screen. How is that possible?

Comment: Because they did start implementing *"user initiated Picture-in-Picture"* which **is not the same** as the web API. Did you click the links in my answer?

Comment: Yes, great job, it works in Chrome! Thank you, I almost understand everyting, greate help @Kaiido!

I am just curios, can you better explain me how they can implement "user initiated Picture-in-Picture" in Firefox does not support it (your great example works in Chrome but doesn't work in FF)..how YouTube and websites like succes to bypass basic browser support?

Comment: It is not Youtube or other webstes that do anything, it's just FF that does add this to their UI, but we programmer have no access to this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Once again, great answers @Kaiido, thank you so much! So, if I implement your example I should provide that option only for Chrome. Where can we track information about progress of implementation this function by FF?

Answer (score 1):

This may be silly, but I had this error and then realized that I had only made a mistake in my camelcase (when used in Google Chrome)! I had entered '.requestPictureinPicture' and not '.requestPictureInPicture' (with the 'i' in "In" capitalized). Once I made this correction, everything of course worked perfectly.